# Bandwidth doesn't update on web-site

Tags: cpanel, bandwidth

I have website with PDF book for download. The book is 300 MB big. I know for sure that in the last two days, I have 50 to 100 downloads. Still, when I go in cpanel, on the right column my Bandwidth stats say that I have 340 megabytes used of total 300 gigabytes transfer.

Why the downloaded PDF books doesn't change my bandwith? I can't really see how much traffic is on my website without this info (I have Google Analytics, and it says that I had 450 different users on my page in the last two days).

Any suggestions?